# Trouble upgrading to couchbase java-client 2.6.1

Tags: java, couchbase

After upgrading the couchbase java-client to 2.6.1, I get the following error on application startup:

```
exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/couchbase/client/encryption/CryptoManager
```

After a quick investigation it looks that a Support for Field-Level Encryption  [was added since 2.6.0](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JCBC-1170).

The problem seems to be the following transitive dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>encryption</artifactId>
        <version>${encryptionextension.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

which is marked as optional, however, it is declared in `DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment` and therefore cannot be optional.

The quick fix for this problem is to add the "encryption" transitive dependency to the classpath explicitly. Nevertheless, it seems to be a bug which will force all the clients to encounter the same problem.

**UPDATE**
The easiest way to reproduce the issue is to invoke the following code:

```
DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

This code is invoked by spring when loading coucbase environment as a spring bean. I've managed to isolate the issue to the single line of code which causes the problem.

Comment: Yes the optional dependency was added as part of 2.6.0 and there shouldn't be instances of the CryptoManager class created. Is it possible to share sample code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It is very easy to reproduce. Just create a simple integration test which uses the 2.6.1 dependency and and defines no encyption dependency. Is there a way I can contact you to discuss in detail?

Comment: Sure, you can contact at subhashni@couchbase.com.

Comment: Note that we couldn't repro it as such.  Are you using Spring by chance?  Spring uses reflection for bean instantiation and that would cause classloading, we believe.  Thus the maven isn't really incorrect, but the use of a framework doing reflection is causing the classload attempt.

Comment: Yes, the Bucket instantiation is managed by spring. Even if this issue is reproducible in this context only, considering the wide spring adoption, the current approach with this new feature should take this issue into consideration

Comment: The current release train of Spring lovelace 3.1.x does address this issue, it will ship with the encryption dependency.

Comment: We are not using spring-data. Just java-client & spring-core. Does this mean that I have to add explicitly the encryption dependency? Isn't this a sign that the encryption dependency should not be optional, in order to work no matter how the client is used?

Comment: Yeah - just ran into this in a Jenkins / Groovy environment.  Upgraded from 2.5.7 -> 2.7.4 and this started occurring.  In 

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.couchbase.client.java.env.CouchbaseEnvironment due to missing dependency com/couchbase/client/encryption/CryptoManager

Comment: Also...  

https://docs.couchbase.com/c-sdk/2.10/encryption.html states that 

Field Level Encryption for all SDKs is a separate package from the Couchbase SDK itself; the APIs are extensions of the SDK, but the SDK does not have a dependency on FLE. This means you can install the relevant SDK without being dependant upon a suite of crypto libraries.

Comment: Yup, it's a bug. Tracking it as https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JCBC-1333